# Any better way to slicing numpy array in parametric way in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to do slice operation on numpy array in parametric way in function so I could get expected array element for my computation. I know how to slide the array by index, but I am more interested in slicing array element in parametric way, so no need to indicate the index. In my case, I have coefficient array `c` and power array `p`, I have also parameter `num_order`. Basically, `num_order` decide the index of slicing array. To do so, I have following attempt:

**my attempt**:

```
import numpy as np

c=[1,1/2, -1/6, 1/12]
p= [1,2,3,4]
x = np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21])


def arr_pow(x, num_order):
    output= []
    for i in range(num_order):
        mul = c[i] * np.power(x, p[i])
        output.append(mul)
    return output
```

so, if `num_order`=2, then I also slice first two term of `c` and `p` doing `c_new = c[:-2],` p_new`=p[:-2]`, `c_new=[1,1/2], p_new=[1,2]` and so on. I am curious is there any better way to do slicing element in two or more array based on param `num_order`. Can anyone point me out any elegant way to make this happen in parameterized function? Any thoughts?

**update**:

instead of doing `c_new=c[:-1], p_new=[:-1]` if `num_order`=3, and `c_new=c[:-2]`, `p_new=p[:-2]` if `num_order=2`, and so on, is there more elegant way (parametric fashion) to do this? Any way of doing this efficiently in python function? Thanks!

Comment: I don't follow.  What does `power` have to do with slicing?  Or even what do you mean by `parametric way`?  First are just slicing 1d arrays?  e.g. `x[i:j]`  or with `slice` object:  `s = slice(i,j); x[s]`.  Show the expected output for all test cases.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for heads up. the nature of the problem is `x` is pixel vector, I want to use Taylor series on each pixel value. I want to come up function so I could use Taylor series on input `x` with any expansion order I want. I need generic function to achieve this. Any possible thoughts? Thanks

Comment: @hpaulj do you have any possible attempt to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the output you want (if you could please update your question to include the expected output that would be helpful):

```
import numpy as np

c = np.array([1, 1 / 2, -1 / 6, 1 / 12])
p = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
x = np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21])


def arr_pow_numpy(x, num_order):
    return c[:num_order, None] * np.power(x[None], p[:num_order, None])


def arr_pow(x, num_order):
    output = []
    for i in range(num_order):
        mul = c[i] * np.power(x, p[i])
        output.append(mul)
    return np.asarray(output)


for num_order in range(1, len(p)):
    assert np.array_equal(arr_pow(x, num_order), arr_pow_numpy(x, num_order)), f"{num_order}"
```

The idea here is to use [NumPy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) plus [NumPy slicing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html) to achieve the result you want without for loops and in a parametric way.

Comment: the nature of the problem is x is pixel vector, I want to use Taylor series on each pixel value from `x`. I want to come up function so I could use Taylor series on input x with any expansion order I want. I want generic function to achieve this. Any possible thoughts?

Comment: it should be right, I am just doing sanity check. Also I want to clarify why I ask this question, so you might have better clarity to understand the question. Could you give few lines of comment on this : `c[:num_order, None] * np.power(x[None], p[:num_order, None])` ? I want to understand the way of doing this. Cheers:)

Comment: When you index an array with `None` you insert an empty axis at that position. For instance, if you wanted to make a multiplication table you could do `np.arange(10)[None] * np.arange(5)[:, None]` which is functionally equivalent to `np.arange(10).reshape(1, 10) * np.arange(5).reshape(5, 1)`. The former is preferred because it uses [views](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/glossary.html#term-view) while the latter uses copies.

Comment: I don't see a link. I'd open a new question and post the link to the new question here.

Comment: it is still about this post and I think I could ask here. what I did is I tried your attempt in tensorflow but I got `invalidArgumentError`. do you have any possible thoughts why is that? You could see my attempt in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jaret20/c2182fa1e694e0d37a88097d13a95b52). Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: @David Hoffman can you help me what's going on when I used your attempt in tensorflow. Any possible update from shared gist? Thanks

Comment: I don’t have any tensorflow experience. I’d recommend asking a new question on Stackoverflow specifically tagged with `tensorflow`. It might also be worthwhile opening an issue on GitHub if you think this is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
num_order = 2
np.array([c[i] * np.power(x, p[i]) for i in range(num_order)])

# Out:
# array([[  1. ,   1. ,   2. ,   3. ,   5. ,   8. ,  13. ,  21. ],
#        [  0.5,   0.5,   2. ,   4.5,  12.5,  32. ,  84.5, 220.5]])
```